# Trying to setup www subdomain results in 'This site can't be reached' or 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain, route53

#### Goal

To get `www.example.com` to point to my web application.

#### Problem

I've been following several tutorials to try and get `www.example.com` to point to my website. I can only get `example.com` and `https://example.com` to work.

For my first attempt, I only tried to use an A name record that would point the www subdomain to my web application. This resulted in a 400 Bad Request error.

For my second attempt, I followed AWS's Tutorials on subdomain creation. In their articles/videos they ask that I create a second hosted zone called `www.example.com`, then use the resulting NS recorded in my first hosted zone called `example.com`. This results in a "This site can’t be reached - DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN".

I think I may have over complicated things with the 2nd hosted zone and probably only need to use a simple A record for the subdomain, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

When I try to run nslookups for the domains, I can see that my `www` subdomain cannot be found.

```
nslookup www.example.com
Server:     2600:1700:4f30:c7c0::1
Address:    2600:1700:4f30:c7c0::1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find www.example.com: No answer
```

```
nslookup example.com
Server:     2600:1700:4f30:c7c0::1
Address:    2600:1700:4f30:c7c0::1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   example.com
Address: 52.2.230.64
Name:   example.com
Address: 54.163.96.24
```

These are screenshots for how I've setup my hosted zones in AWS, maybe I'm putting in something incorrectly and just not catching it?
I've blacked out a TXT record for Pinterest verification and a CNAME record for my HTTPS certification. I think those are supposed to stay secret, but please let me know otherwise if they're needed.

[image]

[image]

#### Side Note

I've already reached out to my domain provider and they stated that there are no complications on their side and that it would need to be configured on my web hosting side. I've tried everything I can, but not sure what else to try!

Comment: where is your CNAME for www pointing to the root domain?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have 3 related problems here.

In the zone for `example.com` you have both an A record and an NS record for `www.example.com`. You need to get rid of one of these. My suggestion would be to keep it simple, remove the `www.example.com` subdomain and leave an A record. This is by far the simpler and more common approach.

The alternative is to get rid of the A record, leave the NS records and then in the `www.example.com` domain add an A record. I would only do this if a different set of people need access to the www domain delegation to those that need access to `example.com` - and even then I'd be super cautious about it because they don't have control to `example.com` which they seem to need anyway.

**Note that in either case, an A record needs to point to an IP address, not a domain name - so your reference `www.example.com` A `example-prod-us-east.1.elasticbeanstalk.com` is incorrect. You probably want to change this to 2 A records with `54.163.96.24` and `52.2.230.64` as per where `example.com` is resolving to at the moment.**

FYI, (at least on Linux systems), you may want to try running

```
 dig +trace www.example.com
```

This command will do a recursive lookup telling you all the steps the lookup goes through and the final result. Note that the final result is nameservers at the moment, not an A record (or CNAME). If you do something similar for `example.com` you get an A record. This is telling you that the problem is with DNS and not the web hosting.

Comment: This is  progress.  You now have the DNS set up correctly - you are now getting the 400 Bad request message from  - so the configuration here needs to be changed so that it knows how to route requests for www.opensprouts.com (presumably the same as for opensprouts.com).  At this point I don't know enough to tell you exactly what to do, but it would seem you need to configure this in EBS (as the system returning the code is an aswelb/2.0 server).  Its also quite possible the problem is with the EC2 instance.  Do you really need such complex hosting?

Comment: I finally discovered that my problem was I didn't set the www subdomain as an allowed host within my Django settings file (-_- I'm embarrassed that I forgot to add that). My 400 Bad Request error is now gone!